# embedding your file hierarchy in html

Tags: html, embed

Is there a way to embed file hierarchy ("or index of") of directory in html. I know of something called apaxy but i'd rather just embed if possible. Is there a way?

Comment: 1. most http servers offer a "directory index" feature. I suggest you take a look into the documentation of your http server. 2. all scripting languages or whatever dynamic component you use inside your http server can generate directory listings. I suggest you take a look at the documentation of whatever language you use. _Sorry if this is vague, but since your question is extremely vague there is nothing more we can say here._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apaxy:
http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/

Is a great .htaccess file and theme to make great sites for downloads.